# How do I list all repositories with the SVNParentPath directive on Apache+SVN?

Tags: svn, apache2, mod-dav-svn

I'm using SVN through Apache with `dav_svn_module` like this:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath C:/svn_repository
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  ...
</Location>
```

This lets me access my repos:

```
C:/svn_repository/repo1
C:/svn_repository/repo2
C:/svn_repository/repo3
```

via these URLs:

```
https://examples.com/svn/repo1
https://examples.com/svn/repo2
https://examples.com/svn/repo3
```

Those URLs work great. When I go to just /svn (no repo name), I get a 403/forbidden response. What I'd like to see if a list of repos. Is that possible?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add this line

```
SVNListParentPath on
```

right under the SVNParentPath.  Restart apache.

Comment: I had to add a trailing / to my Location (<Location /svn/>) to make this work. Thanks! http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?p=21502&sid=888ad3d666f135fb6251766f39a9dd2c

Comment: And if you're using authentication, this thread has some good suggestions: http://www.svnforum.org/threads/35420-SVNListParentPath-AuthzSVNAccessFile-conflict

Comment: Note that as you'll find in the thread that @MattConnolly linked to, it does not appear to be possible to use `SvnListParentPath` with `<Location />` and `AuthzSVNAccessFile`.