# With visualsvn server how to avoid repository listing in https?

Tags: .htaccess, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I've used VisualSVN server since a few years, and since a while i would like to hide repository list in https access.

When you log into visualsvn in https, it redirects you to "/svn/" subfolder and displays the list of repositories as links.

I would like to hide this page, to enforce the users to type the name of repository they want to enter in address bar, then allow them to browse it normally (exactly like it currently does).
I don't want to close remote http access, just to hide the repository listing at login, even for admins, just to hide the full repository list (or protect it behind a hidden page, for example by renaming the "/svn/" first page and disable automatic redirect on it).

I'm sure it is possible by tweaking .htaccess or templates in VSVN configuration files, but I didn't found how to do that cleanly since i'm not used to apache configuration.

Thank you very much

Comment: What VisualSVN Server version do you use? I'm asking because behavior of repository listing was changed in VisualSVN Server 2.6: A repository is no longer displayed in the list of repositories unless a user has explicit access permissions on the repository root. See VisualSVN Server 2.6 release notes for details: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/2.6/

Comment: Good point. I'm using the last one, and you're right about this. But as I said I would like to hide the repositories listing on the "home", for everybody. Or to protect it behind a non "automatically redirected" page. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list all repositories with the SVNParentPath directive on Apache+SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488778/how-do-i-list-all-repositories-with-the-svnparentpath-directive-on-apachesvn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Lazy badger for [your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488778/how-do-i-list-all-repositories-with-the-svnparentpath-directive-on-apachesvn). As this not a specific "VisualSVN" talk I missed it when I was looking for an answer. 
This answer is a bit simpler than what I was expecting but it will do the trick.

So i'm answering myself :

Just turn to "off" the "**SVNListParentPath**" line in C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\conf\httpd.conf (default path).

Rather than the repositories listing, it will display a "forbidden" page.

I've also did something else : I've modified the "**index.html**" in C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\htdocs, to **disable the automatic redirect to "/svn/"** (first meta above body in the file) and to remove anything which tells there is SVN repositories behind the url.

Comment: To the people who downvoted the answer : please explain why, otherwise your downvote is purely useless.